# Me da error en el siguiente codigo y no veo el porque, en Java Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

Trato de desarrollar parte del codigo de un programa que se me solicita y me da este fallo.

Mi código de "AnimalAbstracto" es:

```
public abstract class AnimalAbstracto implements Animal{
    
    public abstract void viveUnaHora(); // Defino el método abstracto "viveUnaHora"
    
    private String nombre; // Encapsulamiento de nuestro atributo.
    
    //Métodos públicos para acceder y modificar mi atributo.
    public void SetNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
    
    public String GetNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

}
```

Comment: Agrega un poco de contexto, donde esta exactamente el error?, el uso de super() indica el uso del constructor de una clase padre, agrega mas detalles.

Comment: Perdon, es que se supone que tengo que haccer todo esto:

Comment: 4 ) Crea la clase “Corral”. Esta tendrá un atributo privado con el siguiente array:
Animal [] animales;
Deberá tener un método constructor que inicialice este array con los siguientes animales:
– Una gallina llamada Federica
– Una gallina llamada Manuela
– Un perro llamado Blacky
– Un perro llamado Dirty
– Un gato llamado Tonet
Crea el siguiente método en dicha clase:
public void simulaUnDía()
Para cada hora del día (entre 0 y 23), dicho método debe mostrar la hora del día. También debe recorrer el array de “animales”, invocando el método “viveUnaHora” de cada animal.

Comment: Y no se exactamente si eso esta bien, pero en eclipse me dice que no es aceptable el codigo imiplementado

Comment: y que dice tu mensaje de error? Yo estoy casi seguro que es porque pusiste una variable privada en la clase abstracta

Comment: Hola Sunil, es difícil saber que pasa sin más información, pero me parece, que el problema está en la declaración de la clase, en ella, usas **implements Animal** no creo que **Animal** sea una interfaz, si estoy en lo cierto, ya tienes la razón de la queja del IDE, debes cambiar **implements** por **extends** para que herede de **Animal**, y por otro lado, no veo la razón de usar esta clase, creo que podrías implementar lo mismo en **Animal**.